# Comodo EV SSL Setup with Nginx - They have only provided 2 files

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I've been having an issue with setting up my SSL cert and I'm a little confused.

To begin with I have the example.com .key, .crt & .csr

I've just had the files that Comodo have sent me, example_com.ca_bundle & example_com.crt

I renamed the example_com.ca_bundle to example_com.crt, moved the old crt and whacked it into Nginx with the .key - but this returns a mismatch error:

```
2016/02/22 12:00:37 [emerg] 1307#0: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/home/callam/keys/cleanably.co.uk.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

My Nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
```

}

server {
        listen 443;

```
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /home/me/keys/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/me/keys/example_com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
```

Where have I gone wrong and what are the correct steps?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows, I was confused because most other guides suggest 3 files at least.

The combined file from Comodo contains 2 of those. Just put the crt you generated with your key before the ones generated by comodo and that's the crt you need to link to in your nginx config.

Comment: could you go into more details? I get 4 files from comodo : 
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt                   
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt                      
STAR_niceshop_co.crt

which one are my private key and my pub key? My understanding was that I needed to bundle files 2 and 4 to make my pubkey. but I get exactly the same error : " failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)"

Answer (score 0):

You’ll get the zip file with the following folders

`CER — CRT Files, PKCS7 File, Plain Text Files`

Open the `CER — CRT File` Folder, you’ll find `5` files

#### concat all the files to a single file by following order

- STAR_domain_filename.crt
- SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle
- AAACertificateServices.crt
- USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt

#### windows

```
type STAR_domain_filenm.crt SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle AAACertificateServices.crt USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

#### Ubuntu

```
cat STAR_domain_filenm.crt SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle AAACertificateServices.crt USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt > ssl-bundle.crt
```

Make sure use this same order, if not then in Nginx it throw an error like said above.